# When is a message charged?

Tags: iphone, sms

I opened my contacts, clicked my friend's name and using his email, sent him a message. My friend's email is associated with an apple account. Yet when the message was delivered, it turned green. Does it mean that I was charged for the message? Is it necessary that the sender is charged whenever the message turns green? I don't have an SMS package or any other prepaid options. I have a simple AT&T plan with limited talk time and 300 MB of data.

My friend lives in a different country and uses an iPod through his home wifi.

P.S.: I have asked this question on the official Apple forum ([link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20004770#20004770)). I think SE is a better place for such questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the text bubble is **green** instead of **blue**, you're sending a **SMS** instead of using *iMessage*, being, therefore, charged for that.

Messages are sent as SMS when iMessage is unavailable, unless you disable this under **Settings / Messages / Send as SMS**.

So, as I understand it, you either sent it to an non Apple ID email address, or the text couldn't reach the receiver through iMessage, changing to *SMS* mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my friends iPod is not connected to any wireless service provider (it's connected through Wi-Fi to the internet, provided by a cable company). Ergo it doesn't have a phone number. Can such a device receive or send an SMS?

Comment: @ShashankSawant No, but if you send an email to a non Apple ID email, it is sent through your Carrier, as MMS, charging you for that.